# Can't load video for iphone Safari/Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, html5-video

I am trying to load a video through QuickTime on click of a Div

```
 $('#VideoPlaceHolder').click(function() {

        var videoElement = document.createElement('video');
        videoElement.setAttribute('src', 'Video.mp4');        

        videoElement[0].play();
        });
```

This code fails to play a video in Iphone. It does load an audio in background in Web Browsers.

Please guide! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of, you need to insert the video element into the DOM before issuing a play. And before playing you must issue a load.

```
$('#VideoPlaceHolder').click(function() {
    var videoElement = document.createElement('video');

    videoElement.src = 'Video.mp4';

    // Inserts video element as a child to the DIV being clicked.
    $(this).append(videoElement);

    // Issue a load, and then play.
    videoElement.load();
    videoElement.play();
});
```

It might be good to know that on most mobile browsers autostart is disabled and the load must be issued after a user click. This is to prevent a browser from starting to download a huge video while the viewer might be on an expensive connection (e.g. data-roaming while on vacation).

Hopefully, this helps.